# Adobe Brackets - Live preview not working - Chrome remote debugging

Tags: php, live, preview, adobe-brackets

I have a problem with Brackets.

I am currently working on XAMPP local server on an PHP project.

Live preview worked fine, but today i cant open it.

This pop-up shows up.

[image]

How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

1. I **uninstalled** Brackets
2. And **deleted its folder** from the %AppData% folder (just copy paste along with % on any explorer window).
3. Then finally **reinstalled** Brackets again.

Everything is working just fine now.